# Difference between the two?

Tags: site-definition, moderation, answers, discussion

So what's the difference between christianity.stackexchange.com and meta.christianity.stackexchange.com ? There was a reference on another question that got me to wondering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a general StackExchange concept.  The main site is for asking questions about the site's theme--Christianity, in this case.  The meta site is for issues related to the site itself.  For example, you seem to have the basic idea already.  You asked this question here, and not on the main site, which is the right way to do it, because this is a question about Christianity.SE, not about Christian doctrine.

Comment: Ahhh, gotcha. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @TheDukeOfMarshall more information at [meta-faq]